# How to use SharedPreferences in android to get value from PhotoView id/image id

Tags: java, android

I am creating an android application, I am displaying images from drawable folder based on the numbering, my activity start showing images from number 1 and I am using buttons to show next or previous image.

I am trying to save the value of image user was viewing while pressed back button using shared preferences. my code looks like this

```
private int currentPage = 1;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_read);
        final Button btnNext = findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        final Button btnBack = findViewById(R.id.btnBack);

listOfObjects = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.object_array);
        images = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.object_image);
        itemImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgSpace);
        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.my_spinner, listOfObjects);;
        spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.my_spinner);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                itemImage.setImageResource(images.getResourceId(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition(), -1));
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
        final ImageView img =  findViewById(R.id.imgSpace);
        PhotoView photoView = (PhotoView) findViewById(R.id.imgSpace);
        img.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier("page_"+currentPage,"drawable",getPackageName()));

 btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() < spinner.getAdapter().getCount()){
      spinner.setSelection(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()+1);
  }            
            }
        } );

}
```

**currentPage** is the variable which I want to save after pressing back button or to go to any other activity and also if user minimises the application, I want to pass it to main activity in order to show the extra button of resume activity and also to show the exact image the user was seeing before pressing the back button when user clicks on resume activity button.
I am using Chris Banes's photoview to show the image. I know how to pass variables and et them in PHP however android is new for me. ANy help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("nameOfSharedPreference", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("nameOfSharedPreference", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putInt("image", R.imageID).commit();

@Override
onBackPressed(){
    image = prefs.getInt("image", defaultValue)  //Default value is taken if the pref doesn't exist yet
}
```

onBackPressed() is called automatically by android when pressing the phone back button. You can call it manually:
onBackPressed();

Comment: SO by just adding this when user will enter into this activity, user will able to see the same image user was seeing? so the code will ignore "private int currentPage = 1" ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question completely but you could write:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("nameOFPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
private int currentPage = prefs.getInt("image", 1);
```

The way it works is it saves a file in nameOfPref in the "image" section so you get it back when the program launches. Here we put 1 as default value so the value it will take is 1 the first time you launch the program. You should write:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor =    getSharedPreferences("nameOfSharedPreference", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putInt("image", idOFImageCurrentlyVIewed).commit();
```

Later in the program each time the user changes image. So it will change the preference and will make sure that when you launch the program back currentImage will take the right value.
In android studio you can look at the file system of emulated phones. For preferences you need to go in Android/data/com.yourPackageName/preferences and you should see your file there if everything goes fine.